# CountDownTimer calls double method

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to explain better. I have this timer, and after it finish counting it should call another class (popup) and after that other function in the same class where the counter is.

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }


        public void onFinish() {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PogresanOdgovor.class);
            i.putExtra("tacanOdgovor", tacanOdg);
            startActivity(i);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);

            brojacPogresnihOdgovora++;
        }
```

After first pass, my score is 2 instead of 1, then 6, the 14...This delayed method is simply the next question:

```
Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            nextQuestion();
            brojacVremena.start();
        }
     };
```

I call exactly the same method as the one in onFinish() when user answer wrong and it works fine.

MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(6000, 1000);

final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

```
        Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
        if (ans.isCorrect) {
            brojacVremena.cancel();
            brojacTacnihOdgovora = brojacTacnihOdgovora + 5;
            Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TACANODGOVOR");
            startActivity(i);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1200);
        }
    else{
        brojacVremena.cancel();
        brojacPogresnihOdgovora++;
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PogresanOdgovor.class);
        i.putExtra("tacanOdgovor", tacanOdg);
        startActivity(i);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);

    }
};
```

Comment: can u plz explain more .  what is brojacVremena? is it CountDownTimer instance, when u are changing value of tacanOdg variable ?

Comment: OK, i will post below that part of the code. brojacVremena is my counter

Answer (score 2):

I found my error. I called my counter twice. Here:

```
nextQuestion(); 
brojacVremena.start();
```

and below in the very same nextQuestion method:

```
public void nextQuestion() {
brojacVremena.start();
.
.
.
```

I don't know how that happened.